# Update returns true, but doesn't update fields

Tags: api, php, wsdl, update

So I am trying to update a custom objects fields through the API, and it says that it is working, but the fields don't update. It's a simple text field I am trying to update. Here is my code:

```
$sObject = new sObject();
$sObject->Id = RECORD_SFID;
$sObject->Lead_Source__c = 'Lead Source';
$sObject->Lead_Source_Detail__c = 'Lead Source Detail';
$sObject->type = 'Lead_Sources__c';
$res = $sf->update([$sObject], 'Lead_Sources__c');
```

This returns

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => RECORD_SFID
    [success] => 1
)
```

But none of the fields are updated. I have an updated wsdl and the fields are writeable by the API. Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Malformed sObject. Fields should have been in an array.